# If/else condition or loop in fetch?

Tags: reactjs

I have an API that I want to fetch, with async componentDidMount(). But this API is abit special, you can only get 1 json object/request.

So if the JSON contains a bike value, I want to fetch from the api again and loop/run untill I no longer get a car value instead of bike.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(CAR_API);
        const json = await response.json();

        if(json.bike == null){
         this.setState({ data: json });
        }else{
           // Fetch again
           const response = await fetch(CAR_API);
           const json = await response.json();
        }
      }
```

Can I do some forloop untill I get a car value?

Comment: I think you should do a recursive method for fetch

Comment: In the case of **Until i get car value?**, Use setInterval after a gap of time to collect the data and clearInterval once you get the desired value.

Comment: FYI, the General approach would be for the API to be unique for each use-case, you can move the entire data fetching call outside the lifecycle and call it recursively when your condition is not yet met.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should call fetch outside the lifecycle hook and make a recursive function

```
fetchCars = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(CAR_API);
  const json = await response.json();
  if (json.bike === null || json.bike === undefined) this.setState({ data: json });
  else this.fetchCars();
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchCars();
}
```

so the idea is if the bike exists in response JSON, this recursive function will re-trigger the fetch request until the condition matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchApi(); 
}
    
fetchApi = async () => {
   const response = await fetch(CAR_API);
   const json = await response.json();

   if(json.bike == null) {
     this.setState({ data: json });
   } else {
      this.fetchApi();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Using loop instead of recursion is much cleaner and simplier solution.

Comment: @radovix what would the loop be initialized with and what would be the termination condition?

Comment: Use infinite loop and break from it when condition is met.

Comment: under the loop, you'd still call fetchApi() and then compare the value with breaking condition? you'd have to duplicate the code when using for loop. The recursive approach is cleaner and easier to understand. General implementation would be to use recursive over for loop format.

Comment: Recursion is never easier to understand than loops. Duplicated 2 lines of codes ain't much of a problem.

Comment: this is perfectly fine, recursion is a valid tool too.

Comment: @radovix I don't see the point to start an argument and criticize someone answer based on a self preference style code.